# Are St. Maximilian Kolbe's writings available in English?

Tags: resource-request, maximilian-kolbe

St. Maximilian Kolbe was known for printing his pamphlets in the years leading up to World War II.  Reportedly, he had some very interesting musings on relativity, the speed of light  and Christ's redemptive power.

I can't find any of his works in English (or Polish for that matter), although I read his quotes now and again.  I've never seen an actual book or collection of writings written by him.

Is there a published collection of his works available anywhere?

Comment: There are a lot of books about him, and I see one Kolbe reader, but I'm specifically looking the pamphlets published by his order in Poland.

Comment: Have you tried Google Books? https://www.google.com/#q=Maximilian+Kolbe&hl=en&prmd=imvnsob&source=lnms&tbm=bks&ei=IsK5TtTNOuKWiQKcztXlBA&sa=X&oi=mode_link&ct=mode&cd=7&sqi=2&ved=0CBoQ_AUoBg&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=3a82ac68bcbcfab4&biw=1366&bih=677

Comment: @justin Yeah, I've been looking for his stuff for a while, never asked any one about it before. Just searched libraries and the Internet to no avail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The writings of St. Maximilian Maria Kolbe are now available in English, published by Nerbini International. See the official web site of the MI: http://mi-international.org.

In the U.S. [the two-volume set](http://content.delivra.com/etapcontent//Marytown/2016/Kolbe%20Writings%20with%20Order%20form%20C.pdf) is available through Marytown Press. See http://marytown.com

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE. For a quick overview of what this site is about, please take the [Site Tour](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour). Thanks for the references. Do you have a direct link to where these writings are available on these websites? If so, it would make your answer more helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I just got this email today, I'll edit your post with the link.

Answer (score 5):

[This site](http://www.missiomariae.net/) appears to be down at the moment, but they claim, "There is no complete English edition of his writings at the present moment in one collected volumes.  Hence, we offer our readers and missionaries the following materials that can be used as supplement for meditation, and/or instruction on Kolbe's Total consecration to the the Immaculate."

[Excerpts from Kolbe's Writings on Total Consecration to Mary](http://www.missiomariae.net/religious-life/spirituality/216-excerpts-from-kolbes-wrtings-on-total-consecration-to-mary.html) ([Google Cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3ahttp://www.missiomariae.net/religious-life/spirituality/216-excerpts-from-kolbes-wrtings-on-total-consecration-to-mary.html&hl=en&strip=1))

Answer (score 5):

You've probably found something by now, but if not, St Maximilian's writings are available online, though mostly in Polish (I found a few articles in Latin) on the website of Niepokalanow (Mary's Town), the Franciscan community founded by St Maximilian near Warsaw, Poland) http://www.niepokalanow.pl/pisma From what I gather, there are 2 volumes published in paper version by the Franciscans of Niepokalanow, http://www.wydawnictwo.niepokalanow.pl/index.php?products=product&prod_id=17 (only 2 links are allowed here, so you'd have to look the other volume up yourself).  Franciscan Friars of the Immaculate are possibly the best source of information on the subject of the availability of any in English. The writings definitely are a worthy reading, as St Maximilian was an extraordinary man, 'the Patron Saint of our difficult century', as Blessed John Paul II called him.

Answer (score 4):

This might be helpful. I say this and thought of you.

https://www.marytown.com/ecommerce/pc-158-7-the-kolbe-reader.aspx

Comment: ***Normally***, link-only answers are strongly discouraged on all StackExchange sites, but in this case, it does answer the question in about the only helpful way possible.  So... +1 for giving a good answer, but just for future reference..

Answer (score 3):

The complete writings of St. Maximilian Mary are available in Italian. A good portion are also available in English. A three-volume paperback version was published years ago, probably in the '80s. I don't have anything on hand, but be assured, a good portion of his writing is out there--well worth reading. You can check with Academy of the Immaculate for a copy of his "Roman Conferences". (Go to [Mary Mediatrix Website](http://www.marymediatrix.com/) and navigate to the "book store".)

Answer (score 3):

There's a newly released book: "She Shall Crush Thy Head: Selected Writings of St. Maximilian Kolbe". It contains a translation of some of St. Maximilian Kolbe's best writings. It can be purchased [here.](http://leoninepublishers.com/bookstore/mariology/she-shall-crush-thy-head.html)

Comment: Welcome! Thanks for contributing. If you haven't already done so, I hope you'll take a minute to take the [tour] and learn [how this site is different from others](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/a/1809/21576).

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Kindle now has the title "Let Yourself Be Led by the Immaculate", written by Maximilian Kolbe, translated from the polish by a Dominican brother.  Most of his works are available in Polish and (in translation) in Russian... but sadly have not yet been translated into English extensively. I hope that after the canonization of Pope John Paul II, a renewed interest in this "Saint of the troubled 20th Century" will occurr, but it just hasn't happened yet. He is a truly remarkable man and a wonderful Saint for anyone to follow and learn from.

While not directly related to your quest for his writings, I wondered if you know about [the National Shrine to Saint Maximilian Kolbe](http://www.marytown.com/content/militia-immaculata)? Their contact email is:   mail@marytown.com and they also have phone numbers, but I have found that sending an email asking questions or for help is usually fruitful. If you send them a question, I am sure someone could help you out and direct you to the proper documents and whether or not they can be obtained in digital or written format.

The title in the Kindle Store:[Let Yourself Be Led by the Immaculate  Kindle Edition by St. Maximilian Kolbe.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00GXKWH3O)