# Italian Version of St. Maxilmian Kolbe writings

Tags: catholicism, resource-request, maximilian-kolbe

I am looking for a digital version of the Italian translations of St. Maxilmilian Kolbe's writings. Where can I find them in digital form? Does that even exist? If not where then can I find hard copies? Would I have to go to Italy? (not a problem, BTW)

Comment: Welcome to the site. We are glad you decided to participate. Here are some meta posts about this site to help you learn how we do it here: [What Christianity.StackExchange is (and more importantly, what it isn't)](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1379) and [How we are different than other sites](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/1808) Please also take the [tour] and see the [help]. I hope to see you post again soon. Please also keep in mind that I and other users are willing to help you, so ask us anything if you need help.

Comment: This type of question is rare on this site, but it seems the community allows them. Ref: [Should we accept "Help me find this thing" questions?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3766)

Comment: I asked [the same question](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/9122/4), except in English, not Italian and a priest (who actually occasionally do answer questions on this site) said that the complete writings were in Italian (not Polish oddly enough).

Answer (score 1):

I can't help you with the digital version; the closest things seem to be the selections of texts that can be found in some websites (for example, visit [the site of the Missionarie dell'Immacolata](http://www.kolbemission.org/flex/cm/pages/ServeBLOB.php/L/IT/IDPagina/38)).

However, you might find some hard copies in specialized bookstores like [this one](http://www.unilibro.it/libro/massimiliano-maria-kolbe-scritti/9788896168004), which defines its availability as "usually available for shipping in 2 weeks" ("normalmente disponibile per la spedizione in 2 settimane").

God bless you as well.

Answer (score 0):

I would reccommend that you contact [the National Shrine of Saint Maximilian Kolbe](http://www.marytown.com/content/national-shrine-of-st-maximilian-kolbe), if you are in the US, as they could most likely help you.

I have emailed them in the past at mail@marytown.com with questions. They have always been very helpful with either getting me the answers I seek, or sending me to someone else who will know the answer.

If you obtain printed versions, and digital ones don't exist yet on the internet, maybe you could be so kind as to offer to create them from your copy! I have found that entering into a deal where I get the paper format and generate digital editions has allowed me to get copies of books I otherwise wouldn't have been able to afford, and I have provided a good deed for all the other people out there looking for the same material. (This is especially true when looking for translations of works that don't have mass-market appeal, but would be greatly appreciated by a small, dedicated following)