# What were St. Maximilian Kolbe's views on general relativity and sanctifying grace?

Tags: catholicism, maximilian-kolbe

I read or heard somewhere that St. Maximilian Kolbe posited that Sanctifying Grace spread throughout the cosmos faster than the speed of light at the moment Jesus died on the cross.  I know his works [have only recently been translated into English](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4508/are-st-maximilian-kolbes-writings-available-in-english).  I have not read them.

Is my understanding of Kolbe's position correct, and what is the source of that summary (beyond Kolbe's original work)?   I suspect that it came from the novels distributed by Catholicity.com which I read some years back but am unable to pin it down.

Comment: According to 2 Timothy 1:9, sanctifying grace predates the cosmos.

Comment: @korvin yes thank you (and Ken). This is why questions should not be asked past midnight. Unfortunately that's when they pop into my head.

Comment: Peter, I once heard "ask, and ye shall receive, seek and ye shall find" and found no time restrictions in the original source document. 8^D

Comment: Although I have no answer for your question, I have two comments that I hope are relevant. (1) If, as a result of Christ's death, God provided sanctifying grace to creatures in some distant galaxy, there would be no need for Him to wait the millions or billions of years that light would need to reach that galaxy from here. God is just as present in that distant galaxy as he is here, and He could act there whenever He wanted. The laws of nature about the rate of propagation of physical influences don't impede God's will. [continued in next comment]

Comment: Even without considering distant galaxies, we have an example right here on earth: The Blessed Virgin Mary was given sanctifying grace from the moment of her conception, because of the merits of Christ's sacrifice on Calvary, even though her conception occurred years before His sacrifice.  (2) It is my understanding that the redemption of the human race required a perfect sacrifice by a human being; this is why the eternal second Person of the Trinity became man to save us. It would seem, then, that sanctifying grace [continued in next comment]

Comment: for non-humans (if they need redemption) would require a perfect sacrifice by one of their species. So Christ's atonement saves us humans but not the folks in distant galaxies.

Comment: In the Orthodox Christian understanding, grace is the uncreated energy of God, undenominated into different types and everywhere present, not emanated or dispensed.  This is a huge difference between Orthodox theology on one hand and Roman Catholic/Protestant theology on the other, but it is not the first thing that seems to come to mind when looking at differences between the faiths.

Comment: The procurator of his cause goes into great detail on St. Maximilian's  scientific views. However  the book that would explain this is Fr. Antonio Ricciardi, OFM Conv.'s works for the official Cause of Beatification and/or Canonization. It will not be found in his popular editions of St. Maximilian's biography: [Saint Maximilian Kolbe](http://www.theotokos.org.uk/pages/recbooks/misc/maxkolbe.html). The official edition which he wrote for the Congregation for the Causes of Saints is quite long  and is full of very interesting details. I am sure an English copy does exist somewhere.